# How do I filter options without having everything reappear during transitions?

Tags: jquery, html, css, filter

I am trying to achieve a filter with buttons where you click on a button and certain panels on the page get filtered out. Between w3schools and stack overflow, I've been able to figure out the basics, but I'm having trouble with the animation.

**Problem:**
Here's what's happening now. Let's say I *only* have Filter 1 options showing.

- I click on Filter 2
- *All panels* for Filters 1,2, and 3 appear
- Options for Filters for 1 and 3 fade out
- Options for Filter 2 fade in

How can I get it to where everything stops appearing between transitions? I am trying to achieve something like this:

- Options for Filter 1 are showing
- I click on Filter 2
- Filter 1 options fade out
- Filter 2 options fade in

I feel like there might be an easy fix to this, but I haven't been able to find anything (maybe I don't know what to look for?). I thought of trying a big if/else loop that read something like, "if filter 1 is selected and filter 2 was just chosen, fade out filter 1 and fade in filter 2". But that seemed messy.

Thanks for any help.

Buttons and Panel Structure:

```
<div id='filter'>
    <center>
        <button class='all'>Show All</button>
        <button class='filter1'>Filter 1</button>
        <button class='filter2'>Filter 2</button>
        <button class='filter3'>Filter 3</button>
    </center>
</div>

<div class='post filter1 all'>
     <div class="col-sm-6"> 
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                   <a href="lessons/option1.php"><img 
                   src="images/option1.png" alt="" class="standard-image">
                   </a> 
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Filter Code:

```
<script>
$("#filter button").each(function() {
    $(this).on("click", function(){
        var filtertag = $(this).attr('class');
        $('.post').fadeIn();
        $('.post:not(.' + filtertag + ')').fadeOut();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can't you just include the filtertag in the selector for the fade in? `$('.post.' + filtertag).fadeIn();`

Comment: @npearson Yeah...wow. That fixed it. I've been looking at this for hours trying to figure that out. Thanks!

Comment: Great, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to only fade in the matching elements. Also, the `.each()` here is unnecessary because `.on()` already attaches the handler to each of the matched elements.

```js
$("#filter button").on("click", function(){
  var filtertag = $(this).attr('class');
  $('.post.' + filtertag).fadeIn();
  $('.post:not(.' + filtertag + ')').fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.post.all { display: none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='filter'>
    <center>
        <button class='all'>Show All</button>
        <button class='filter1'>Filter 1</button>
        <button class='filter2'>Filter 2</button>
        <button class='filter3'>Filter 3</button>
    </center>
</div>

<div class='post filter1 all'>
Filter 1
</div>

<div class='post filter2 all'>
Filter 2
</div>

<div class='post filter3 all'>
Filter 3
</div>
```

Comment: Shamelessly plugging my answer from the comments :)

Answer (score 0):

I would put a conditional in your script to only make visible elements faceOut(), this can be done like so:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

       $("#filter button").click(function(){
            var filtertag = $(this).attr('class');

            $('.post:not(.'+filtertag+')').each(function(){ //gets all the non-filtered elements
                 if($(this).css('display') != 'none')
                    $(this).fadeOut(); //only fades out elements that are currently visible
            });

            $('.post').fadeIn(); //displays filter
       }); //end of filter button click

    }); //this is good practice
</script>
```

Comment: It almost works. Everything happens like expected, but for some reason all of the options fade back in again. So it fades the right options out, fades the right ones back in, and then all the options show up on the page again. I thought it had something to do with having two classes (i.e. filter1 all), but even removing all didn't work.